# Disable button after click in React

Tags: reactjs

I have this piece of code but can't work out how I can disable the button after Pay is clicked:

```
        } else if (paymentMethod.name === "Pay by Cash") {
            return (
                <Tab.Pane eventKey={paymentMethod.id} key={key}>
                    <h6 className="mb-3 mt-0 mb-3">Cash</h6>
                    {this.state.paymentMethodSelectionError && this.state.paymentMethodSelectionError !== "" && <Alert key="error_div" variant="danger">{this.state.paymentMethodSelectionError}</Alert>}
                    <p>You are paying by cash</p>
                    <Form.Group className="mb-0">
                        <Button className="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg"
                            onClick={() => {
                                this.setState({
                                    selectedPaymentMethod: "not-charged",
                                    paymentGateway: paymentMethod.id
                                }, () => {
                                    this.setPaymentMethod()
                                })
                            }}>
                            PAY £{this.state.totalPay}<Icofont icon="long-arrow-right" /></Button>
                    </Form.Group>
                </Tab.Pane>)
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You can put a `state` for disabling your button:

```js
this.state = {
  disabled: false
}
```

In click function, change it to `true`:

```js
const clickButton = () => {
  this.setState({ disabled: true });
}
```

Then change your HTML to something like this:

```html
<button type="button" disabled={ this.state.disabled }>Click Me!</button>
```

Preview:
[Here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/laughing-darwin-flpee?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Sorry I am a newbie on React, could you show an example using the code above

Comment: @Rutnet I added a link.

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare a new state variable to take care of the disabled button:

`const [buttonState,setButtonState]=useState(false)`

2. Attach a onClick handler to disable the button and also manage the disabled property of the button.

`<button onClick={()=>{ setButtonState(true)}}  disabled={buttonState}> PAY </button>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `state` to control the button state

Preview for both Functional and Class components

[Codesandbox Preview Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-bird-k56l2?file=/src/App.js)